# Click to view information on each thumb post

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want click on each button to view information in each posts but it view all when I click on it.

Here is my example. I have HTML like:

```
<div class='list post'>
    <div class='post'>
        <div class='btn'>btn</div>
        <div class='hidden'>Hidden Info 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class='post'>
        <div class='btn'>btn</div>
        <div class='hidden'>Hidden Info 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='post'>
        <div class='btn'>btn</div>
        <div class='hidden'>Hidden Info 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I use onclick like:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').css({"visibility":"visible"});
});
```

But it is not working. I want to use toggle or something like that but I donot know how to do.

Please check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X2kW4/)

Comment: You can do something like this. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/X2kW4/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to target current clicked `.btn` button along with **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** to target next immediate sibling of clicked button which is `.hidden` div:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
    $(this).next().css({"visibility":"visible"});
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2kW4/6/)**

Comment: but it does not close when I press button2

Comment: "false" should "hidden"

Comment: what happen if I move button to any position in class .post (it is not in order)?

Comment: @user2728514 You can use `.siblings()`: `$(this).siblings('.hidden ').css({"visibility":"visible"});`

Comment: and more when I click again it is not close ? thank your help

Comment: @user2728514 Did you check the demo?

Comment: I think we should use toggle but I do not know how to use it. I will close when I click on second time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').css({"visibility":"visible"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:

$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
    $(this).next().css({"visibility":"visible"});

});

You can also check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/X2kW4/7/
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to change the the visibility property. Instead add/remove visibility class ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2kW4/8/)):

CSS

```
.post {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px;
    background: #cd4900; 
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.post .btn {
    margin-top: 5px !important; 
    width: 80%; 
    padding: 5px; 
    background: green; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    cursor: pointer
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible !important;
}

.info {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).next('.info').hasClass('visible') === false)
    {
        $('.visible').removeClass('visible');
        $(this).next('.info').addClass('visible');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='list post'>
    <div class='post'>
        <div class='btn'>btn</div>
        <div class='info'>Hidden Info 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class='post'>
        <div class='btn'>btn</div>
        <div class='info'>Hidden Info 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='post'>
        <div class='btn'>btn</div>
        <div class='info'>Hidden Info 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```